# javafx self-contained package

Tags: javafx-2

I created the javafx standalone application using netbeans by copying the following snippet into build.xml file

```
<target name ="-post-jfx-deploy">
<fx:deploy width="${javafx.run.width}" height="${javafx.run.height}"
           nativeBundles="all"
           outdir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" outfile="${application.title}">
    <fx:application name="${application.title}" mainClass="${javafx.main.class}"/>
    <fx:resources>
        <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
    </fx:resources>
    <fx:info title="${application.title}" vendor="${application.vendor}"/>
</fx:deploy>
</target>
```

I had jdk environment for x64 bit version so it created application that runs in only x64 bit version of windows or operating systems. Can anyone tell how should I change the deploy method to make application runnable on x86 bit systems. By default netbeans took up 64bit version of jdk environment

Answer (score 0):

You could combine Maven with Ant on the following way:

- Defining a Maven artifact for JDK
- Using maven-dependency-plugin
- Using [`unzip`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html) Ant task
- Using [`<fx:platform>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/javafx_ant_task_reference.html#CIAEEFCJ)

### Defining Maven artifact for JDK

Defining Maven artifacts for JDK x86 and JDK x64. It may sounds weird at first time, but thinking in a continuous integration environment, it makes sense at all.

You just zip an ordinary JDK folder and deploy it as a Maven artifact.

Then your Maven project will depend on:

```
<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.8.112</jdk.version>
    <!-- can be '64' or '32' -->
    <cpu.arch>64</cpu.arch>
</properties>

</dependencies>
    <!-- other dependencies goes here -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.my.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>jre-linux-${cpu.arch}</artifactId>
        <version>${jre.version}</version>
        <type>zip</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Note**: I'm running on Debian, but it's totally applicable to Windows environment too.

### Using maven-dependency-plugin

Add the [`maven-dependency-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/). It will copy all your dependencies (includind your JDK zip file defined on dependencies section) to the `/target/dist/lib` folder.
We'll use it soon.
The plugin configuration looks like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                <outputDirectory>${application.dist}/lib</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

### Using `unzip` Ant task

Now before your JavaFX Ant tasks, you must tell Ant to extract your JDK dependency into a folder.
It must be set **BEFORE** the task who will bundle your JavaFX application.

```
<unzip src="${application.dist}/lib/jdk-linux-${cpu.arch}-${jdk.version}.zip"
                                       dest="${extra.dir}/jdk"/>
```

### Using `<fx:platform>`

And finally, at your [`<fx:deploy>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/javafx_ant_task_reference.html#CIABIFCI) tag you must add a [`<fx:platform>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/javafx_ant_task_reference.html#CIAEEFCJ) child tag, adding the `basedir` attribute as your previous `jdk` folder, like:

```
<fx:deploy ...>
    <fx:platform javafx="8.0+" basedir="${extra.dir}/jdk" />
</fx:deploy>
```

The Maven logs will be similar to this:

```
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (default) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
    [unzip] Expanding: /home/danilo/development/temp/my-app/target/dist/lib/jdk-linux-64-1.8.112.zip into /home/danilo/development/temp/my-app/target/extras/jdk
Using base JDK at: /home/danilo/development/temp/my-app/target/extras/jdk/jre
Using base JDK at: /home/danilo/development/temp/my-app/target/extras/jdk/jre
Creating app bundle: /home/danilo/development/temp/my-app/target/dist/bundles/my-app
Debian packages should specify a license.  The absence of a license will cause some linux distributions to complain about the quality of the application.
  Using default package resource [menu icon]  (add package/linux/my-app.png to the class path to customize)
  Using default package resource [Menu shortcut descriptor]  (add package/linux/my-app.desktop to the class path to customize)
  Using default package resource [DEB control file]  (add package/linux/control to the class path to customize)
  Using default package resource [DEB preinstall script]  (add package/linux/preinst to the class path to customize)
  Using default package resource [DEB prerm script]  (add package/linux/prerm to the class path to customize)
  Using default package resource [DEB postinstall script]  (add package/linux/postinst to the class path to customize)
  Using default package resource [DEB postrm script]  (add package/linux/postrm to the class path to customize)
  Using custom package resource [DEB copyright file]  (loaded from package/linux/copyright)
dpkg-deb: construindo pacote 'my-app' em '/home/danilo/development/temp/my-app/target/dist/bundles/my-app-1.0.deb'.
Package (.deb) saved to: /home/danilo/development/temp/my-app/target/dist/bundles/my-app-1.0.deb
  Config files are saved to /tmp/fxbundler8773603423891700338/linux. Use them to customize package.
Bundler RPM Bundle skipped because of a configuration problem: Can not find rpmbuild {0} or newer.  
Advice to fix:   Install packages needed to build RPM, version {0} or newer.
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8:34.875s
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/253M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Conclusion

When you need to deliver your application on a x86 environment, just override the `cpu.arch` Maven property at build time:

```
mvn -Dcpu.arch=32 clean install
```

Now it's easier to set up your continuous integration. If you would use [Jenkins CI](https://jenkins.io), for example, you can create 2 different jobs and run it as needed.

I pushed the whole project to a Github repository. You can check it here: https://github.com/daniloguimaraes/javafx-multiple-jre-versions